# How do I make my system to detect if a input word is in an array

Tags: c, function, if-statement, return

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Detect Number Function
int hasNumbers(const char *word) {
    int len = strlen(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (word[i] >= '0' && word[i] <= '9') {
            return 1; // Found a digit
        }
    }
    return 0; // No digits found
}

//Detect Symbol Function
int containsSymbol(const char *word) {
    while (*word) {
        if ((*word >= 'A' && *word <= 'Z') || (*word >= 'a' && *word <= 'z') || (*word >= '0' && *word <= '9') || *word == ' ') {
            word++;
        } 
        else {
            return 1; // Symbol found
        }
    }
    return 0; // No symbols found
}

//Detect Centre Letter
int containsLetterL(const char *word) {
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (word[i] == 'C' || word[i] == 'c') {
            return 0;  // 'L' or 'l' found
        }
    }
    return 1;  // 'L' or 'l' not found
}

//Detect Word in Array
int isWordInArray(char word[], char words[100][100], int wordCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        printf("CATS\n");
        if (strcmp(word, words[i]) == 0) {
            return 0;  // Word is found in the array
        }
        printf("DOGS\n");
    }
    return 1;  // Word is not found in the array
}

/*
int isWordInArray2(char word[100], char words[100][100], int wordCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        if (strcmp(word, words[i]) == 0) {
            return 1;  // Word is found in the array
        }
    }
    return 0;  // Word is not found in the array
}
*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main () {
    
    //Transfer Word in Text File to Array
    FILE *file;
    char wordA1[100]; // Assuming a maximum word length of 99 characters
    char words_array[100][100]; // Assuming a maximum of 100 words in the file
    
    // Open the file for reading
    file = fopen("wordlist_Game1.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File not found or cannot be opened.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int wordCountTextFile = 0;
    // Read words from the file and store them in the array
    while (fscanf(file, "%99s", wordA1) == 1) {
        strcpy(words_array[wordCountTextFile], wordA1);
        wordCountTextFile++;
    }
    // Close the file
    fclose(file);
    
    // Main Program
    char word[100];
    int wordCount = sizeof(word) / sizeof(words_array[0]);
    while (1) {
        printf("\nHere is your puzzle:\n");
        printf(" C T U L H N A\n");
        printf("Guess a word or END to quit: ");
        scanf("%s", word);
        printf("%s\n", word);
        
        //Detect END
        if (strcmp(word, "END") == 0) {
            printf("You entered 'END.' Exiting the loop.\n");
            break;
        }
        
        //Detect Number
        else if (hasNumbers(word)) {
            printf("The word contains numbers.\n");
        }
        
        
        //Detect Symbol
        else if (containsSymbol(word)) {
            printf("The word contains symbols.\n");
        }
        
        //Detect Centre Letter
        else if (containsLetterL(word)) {
            printf("The word doesn't contains centre letter 'C'.\n");
        } 
        
        
        //Detect Word in Array
        else if (isWordInArray(word, words_array, wordCount)) {
            printf("%s is in the array.\n", word);
        }
        
        /*
        //Detect Word in Array
        else if (isWordInArray2(word, words_array, wordCount)) {
            printf("%s is NOT the array.\n", word);
        }
        */
    }   
}
```

This code is about detecting a specific word that follows these rules. Every function works just fine except for isWordInArray function. This function is to detect the word if in the array. I want it to tell me if the word is not the array and repeat the loop. And if the word is in the array, then the system will continue the if-else statement. The problem is it skips the part where it tells me whether the word is in the array. so yeah

Comment: Use the built-in function `isalnum()` to tell if a character is a letter or number.

Comment: Why does the function `containsLetterL()` check for the letter `C`?

Comment: All your return values are backwards. In C, `0` is false, non-zero is true.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause:  isWordInArray() was failing to perform correctly for multiple reasons:

1. isWordInArray() was returning false(0) when word found and true(1) for not found
2. Code was passing 'wordCount' as parameter to isWordInArray(), but 'wordCount' evaluates to 1 -- not the actual word count.  Hence, *the full list was never parsed*.  We remedy this by passing wordCountTextFile to isWordInArray().  We have the actual word count from the read operation, so why not use it?

Below is a compile-able, working subset of your code with fixes and comments applied:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    isWordInArray()
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int isWordInArray(char word[], char words[100][100], int wordCount) 
{
    int i;

    /* Updated:  Added some troubleshooting print outs */
    printf("isWordInArray() reports list -- wordcount = %d\n", wordCount);
    for(i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) 
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, words[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) 
    {
        if(strcmp(word, words[i]) == 0) 
        {
            return 1;  /* Updated to 1 ( Word is found in the array) */
        }
    }
    return 0;  /* Updated to 0 ( Word is NOT found in the array) */
}


int main()
{
    
    //Transfer Word in Text File to Array
    FILE *file;
    char wordA1[100]; 
    char words_array[100][100]; 
    int wordCountTextFile = 0;
    char word[100];
    int wordCount = sizeof(word) / sizeof(words_array[0]); /* NOTE!: This evaluates to 1 */
    
    file = fopen("wordlist_Game1.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File not found or cannot be opened.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("wordCount:  %d\n", wordCount);  /* Added:  This will print "1" */
    
    while (fscanf(file, "%99s", wordA1) == 1) 
    {
        strcpy(words_array[wordCountTextFile], wordA1);
        wordCountTextFile++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    
    // Main Program
    while (1) 
    {
        printf("\nHere is your puzzle:\n");
        printf(" C T U L H N A\n");
        printf("Guess a word or 'q' to quit: ");
        scanf("%s", word);
        printf("%s\n", word);
        
        //Detect END
        if (strcmp(word, "END") == 0)
        {
            printf("You entered 'END' Exiting the loop.\n");
            break;
        }
        //Detect Word in Array
        else 
        {
            /* Update:  param wordCountTextFile instead of wordCount*/
            if (isWordInArray(word, words_array, wordCountTextFile))  
                printf("%s IS in the array!!!\n", word); /* Updated */
            else
                printf("%s is NOT in the array.\n", word); /* Added */
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```